# WCF using proxy objects on the server during deserialization

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, dynamic-proxy

I'm trying to keep track of changed properties on a PUT request in WCF (we're doing REST instead of SOAP). I have an idea that I'm trying to vet, but I can't get past this one piece.

At some point when the request is coming in, the body (JSON, XML, etc) is deserialized into an object that is later passed into our WCF service method.

i.e. At some point, WCF must be doing something essentially like this

```
User u = new User();
u.FirstName = ...
u.LastName = ...
u.Email = ...
```

I want to change the first line so that the User object is retrieved from a proxy generator (like `Castle.DynamicProxy`):

```
User u = _proxyGenerator.NewObject<User>();
u.FirstName = ...
u.LastName = ...
u.Email = ...
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? Maybe I have to make my own deserializer?